# Организация охлаждения пк

Tags: пк

Столкнулся с такой загвоздкой, собираю пк и хочу установить сжо , ставить решил на переднюю панель, в идеале хотел бы воткнуть шлангами вниз, корпус позволяет, по придётся пожертвовать вентилятором снизу(на вдув), т.к шланги будут идти через место для вентилятора.
Вопрос заключается в том, как лучше сделать, шланги вниз и пожертвовать вентилятором или же установить шлангами вверх и установить вентилятор.
Просто если жертвовать, то получится что на вдув будут работать только 3 вентиля на передней панели и будь они будут воздух от радиатора.
Также будет сверху 3 и сзади 1 на выдув

Answer (score 0):

Обычно сжо ставят на верхнюю панель, но если вы хотите установить сжо спереди то тут уже на ваше усмотрение. Я считаю что в данном случае вы можете пожертвовать одним вентилятором так как по описанию проблемы я понял что у вас их всего 7. Так же я бы вам советовал некоторые вентиляторы поменять на выдув, подробнее можете узнать здесь > https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2IO2sgUG0PI

Comment: На верхнюю не вариант так как сборка с упором на процессор и хочется чтобы он был как можно холоднее, к тому же он сам по себе довольно тёплый
Все верно, вентиляторов 7 
Спасибо за ответ !